# React view isn't getting updated even after redux store is being upated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

After the page load the changes to the `store` are **not** being captured by the `react`, but if i make any changes to the any of the `reducer files` after a *live-reload* the entire page starts working, but if i reload the page the becomes the same and store updates stop being rendered.

i have tried a lot of things already, diffrent store configuarations, different methods of getting store values namely connect and useSelector.

i have checked dispatch and stores with logs they are working fine, selectors seem not be the issue as well.

I have wasted more than 4 hours on something that i was supposed to take 30mins, any help would be nice to catch whatever i am missing.

link to code sandbox sample here, https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-oskar-30ow2z?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there appears to be some issue with using StrictMode and ReactDOMClient.createRoot. Perhaps you could remove the strict mode in index.js or just use ReactDOM.render. I tried with your sandbox removing the strict mode and it appears to be working fine.
Here is the updated sandbox -
https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-sun-6u5icq?file=/src/index.js